# How to restrict 2 recipient signs from a same device in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I want to 2 recipient [ user and witness] to use the same device or ip address to sign the document sent via docusign.

Please let me know if i can achieve this in docusign

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using in-person signing? That would require the "host" of the signing session to be a DocuSign user in your account though, but process operates under the assumption that the signer and witness are at the same location.

Alternatively, this question is asked quite often and what you need to have a serious think about is whether the witness is required at all. In most use cases, DocuSign effectively replaces the need for a witness as DocuSign itself is witnessing the signature, authenticating the recipient and recording all the actions of the recipient for you. In all but legal use cases (like notarization) it's usually found that the traditional witness signature is no longer required as a result.

Comment: I agree that 'in person signing' is a helpful offering to encourage the same device use for a given transaction. However, there is nothing preventing a host from starting a signing session on tabletA, and then resuming an incomplete signing workflow on tabletB.